# Getting the move constructor/assignment operator to be used

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define P_(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

class B {
public:
    B() { P_("B::B()"); }
    B(const B&) { P_("B::B(const B&)"); }
    B(B&&) { P_("B::B(B&&)"); }
    ~B() { P_("B::~B()"); }

    B& operator=(const B&) { P_("B::op=(const B&)"); return *this; }
    B& operator=(B&& b) { P_("B::op=(B&&)"); return *this; }
};

class Foo {
public:
    void setB(const B& b) { mB = b; }
private:
    B mB;
};

B genB() {
    return B();
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.setB(genB());
}
```

Suppose `B` is a type that is difficult to copy-construct. I'd like to generate some `B` (with the function `genB`) and store it in a `Foo`. Since `genB` returns a temporary result, I'd expect that a move constructor would be used.

However, when I run the code, I get this output:

```
B::B()
B::B()
B::op=(const B&)
B::~B()
B::~B()
```

This clearly shows that two B's get created and destroyed, but that the second is a copy, and not a move of the first.

What is the best way to get move constructors used whenever possible?

- Do I need to call std::move() somewhere?
- Do I need a separate overload for a `B&` and a `B&&`?
- Is there something else entirely that I'm missing?

Comment: (Actually, the first `B` is assigned to become a copy of the second.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overload that `setB` function:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void setB(const B& b) { mB = b; }
    void setB(B&& b) { mB = std::move(b); }
private:
    B mB;
};
```

Or, you can use the "pass by value" way:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void setB(B b) { mB = std::move(b); }
private:
    B mB;
};
```

Here, the parameter `b` will be move constructed when possible or copy constructed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The first `B` instance is the one created when creating your `Foo` instance :

```
Foo f;
```

This is because your `Foo` class has a `B` member called `mB`.

The second `B` instance is the one created by the `genB()` call.

The assignment operator is called because of the assignment you perform in the `Foo::setB` function :

```
mB = b;
```

Nowhere is there a chance to use a copy or move constructor.